# can't find symbol sleep(int) & printen(int)

Tags: java, scite

I Want Help Related to Sleep() and printen()

```
    import java.util.*;
public class example
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int i = 1;
    int a = 4;
    while( i < 4 )
        {
            i++;
            a--;
            sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t The Game Begins In...");
            System.out.print("\t\t\t\t " + a);
        }

        }
   }
```

I got Errors

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol  : method sleep(int)
>
> location: class example
>
> sleep(1000);

Please Help me to solve this

Comment: I feel like a compiler, I cannot find them either, what are they supposed to be? `Thread.sleep(...)` maybe?

Comment: Well, what *is* `printen`?!

Comment: Well where do you *think* those methods come from? I suspect you mean `println`, but `System.out.println` - and I suspect you mean `Thread.sleep`. But I would strongly suggest getting a good Java book or tutorial at this point. Stack Overflow is great for tackling specific problems, but it's not a good way to learn the basics of a language.

Comment: no its not magical

Comment: i also have coding that they have printen(4); and sleep(1000);

Comment: @MJM Then those must either be defined in the same file or imported from somewhere.

Comment: no it is real my friend has used this codes.

Comment: You should REALLY get a Java Book and / or read some tutorials. And on top of that you should learn how to post good questions. Your code cannot and will never work in the form present in your question. And that behaviour is absolutely correct - period. The fact that someone else somewhere else on the world has some function named the same and is successfully calling it does not matter to us and should not matter to you. If you have access to the working code take a look at all the differences - I guarantee you there is either some static import, or the method is defined or something like that

Comment: On the short sight, try `Thread.sleep(1000);` instead. In the longer run, make up your mind about where you expect methods to come from when you try to use them.

Comment: Thread.sleep(..)  How to use it ????????

Comment: *"How to use it"*??? Well, basically you write ... `Thread.sleep(1000);` - done.

Comment: i tried it but i didn't get any output

Comment: Hopeless. Read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site please.

Comment: you are not supposed to get any output, it just tells the program to do nothing for the specified amount of time

Comment: I think there should be another stack site that just has coding tutorials:)

Comment: i am the new user on this site...

Comment: and thanx i got the output

Comment: If someone gave you a code example that doesn’t work when you try to use it — they are probably the right one to ask about it. Glad you made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class example
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int i = 1;
    int a = 4;
    while( i < 4 )
        {
            i++;
            a--;
            try {
            // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
           Thread.sleep(100);
           } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
           }
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t The Game Begins In...");
            System.out.print("\t\t\t\t " + a);
        }

        }
   }

Output

The Game Begins In...
                 3               The Game Begins In...
                 2               The Game Begins In...
                 1
```